# How do I explain Euler method?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

The explicit Euler method for numerically solving the begining values of differential equation $x′=f(t,x),x(t_0)=x_0$ on the interval $I = [t_0, T]$ is given by

$x_{k+1}=x_k+hf(t_k,x_k),k=0,…,N−1$  with $h = (T - t_0) / N, N ∈ N. $

$X_k$ is an approximation of the exact solution $x(t)$ of the begining values at time $t_k: = t_0 + kh, k = 0, ..., N.$ By linear interpolation between the points $(t_k, x_k)$ and $(t_{k + 1}, x_{k + 1}), k = 0, ..., N -1,$ we obtain a approximation solution $x_h(t)$.

Can someone tell if this sketch is good?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The graph looks good. You could think about including a second step to emphasize, that the approximation error accumulates from step to step. But the main point of using the slope at $ x_k $ to approximate $ x_{k+1} $ is clear form the graph.

Cheers

Comment: How should I emphasize second step?

Comment: Maybe you could put in a second slope at $ x_k+1 $ and go another step.

Comment: at $ x_{k+1} $ of course

Comment: Hm I' m not sure if I know how to do it @J.Bowkun

Comment: Can you check now @J.Bowkun

Comment: I would put in at least two tangent lines to emphesize the sloaps the method uses for $x_{k+1}$

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand can you make little sketch?

Comment: I see. You added the second picture to the first one. I thought you replaced the first one. Both togther are good imo.